# Pass var from js to php using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making a calculator web app in PHP. The front end is using HTML, CSS, and JS. In my JS file, I am trying to pass a var to PHP using ajax. Here's what I have so far:

```
// Get all the keys from document
var keys = document.querySelectorAll('#calc span');
var operators = ['+', '-', 'x', '÷'];
var decimalAdded = false;

// Add onclick event to all the keys and perform operations
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
keys[i].onclick = function(e) {
    // Get the input and button values
    var input = document.querySelector('.screen');
    var inputVal = input.innerHTML;
    var btnVal = this.innerHTML;

    // Now, just append the key values (btnValue) to the input string and finally use javascript's eval function to get the result
    // If clear key is pressed, erase everything
    if(btnVal == 'C' || btnVal == 'AC') {
        input.innerHTML = '';
        decimalAdded = false;
    }

    // If eval key is pressed, calculate and display the result
    else if(btnVal == '=') {
        var equation = inputVal;
        var lastChar = equation[equation.length - 1];

        // Replace all instances of x and ÷ with * and / respectively. This can be done easily using regex and the 'g' tag which will replace all instances of the matched character/substring
        equation = equation.replace(/x/g, '*').replace(/÷/g, '/');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "calc.php",
            data: {'passVal': equation},
            success: function(data) {

                    alert(data);

            }
        });
```

I'm not seeing anything in my alerts and it's also not posting to php file I specified. If I do the following on the other hand, I get my data in the alert but still not sure how to pass to php file:

```
....rest of code
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calc.php",
            data: {'passVal': equation},
            success: function(data) {
                    alert(equation);
             }
        });
```

Comment: I think you're looking for Javascript, not PHP

Comment: @RobbieAverill agreed

Comment: There are plenty of way to get it out. What did you try?

Comment: You will need to create a form that posts back to your web server. PHP (or whatever framework you are using) can then access the post parameters. If you would rather not have a form you can also use Javascript - I recommend via jQuery - to submit a post request to the web server. Either way, you need a post route in PHP to receive the request.

Answer (score 1):

**In Javascript** (because I think that this is what you are looking for) :

```js
var elementValue = document.querySelector('span').value;
//or var elementValue = document.getElementById('idhere').value;
```

```html
<span class="on">AC</span>
<span>(</span>
<span>)</span>
```

Comment: I don't think I can pass JS variables to php

Comment: If you did your research and had any idea how Javascript worked, you'd think otherwise. The technique is called ajax. It's how web pages update data without refreshing the browser. I'd suggest you go read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp), and then implement a version of what @T. Bragg suggested, because just assuming you can't pass variables from Javascript to PHP without even trying to do your homework is sad